# Extract two consecutive nouns using spaCy

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

Here is a simple dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
product = ['knife', 'box set', 'beautiful jewellery set on sale', 'green']
df = pd.DataFrame(product, columns = ['product_name'])
df
```

The output as follows:

|  | product_name |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | knife |
| 1 | box set |
| 2 | beautiful jewellery set on sale |
| 3 | green |

I want to categorise these products by extracting two consecutive nouns if needed. So far I have the following, but the categories are presented by only one noun for all cases:

```
!pip install -q --upgrade spacy

import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

category=[]
for i in df['product_name'].tolist():
    doc = nlp(i)
    for t in doc:
      if t.pos_ in ['NOUN']:
        category.append(f'{t}')
        break
    if t.pos_ not in ['NOUN']:
      category.append('NaN')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(category, columns =['product_category'])
df1
```

The output I have:

|  | product_category |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | knife |
| 1 | set |
| 2 | jewellery |
| 3 | NaN |

The expected output:

|  | product_category |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | knife |
| 1 | box set |
| 2 | jewellery set |
| 3 | NaN |

Is it possible to introduce some additional conditions to the code to extract two nouns if they follow one after another?

Comment: Use `matcher` with the corresponding pattern.

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/WGSS7B

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much Wiktor for your kind help. I will start learning the method you showed.

Comment: Can you please clarify what output you want? The one I showed in the above link?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've updated the question and included the expected output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Dear Wiktor, thank you very much for this elegant solution! It is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

product = ['knife', 'box set', 'beautiful jewellery set on sale', 'green']
df = pd.DataFrame(product, columns = ['product_name'])

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
matcher = spacy.matcher.Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{'POS': 'NOUN'},{'POS': 'NOUN','OP':'?'}]
matcher.add('NOUN_PATTERN', [pattern])

def get_two_nouns(x):
    doc = nlp(x)
    results = []
    for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc):
        span = doc[start:end]
        results.append(span.text)
    return max(results, key = lambda x: len(x.split()), default=np.nan)

df['product_name'].apply(get_two_nouns)
```

Output:

```
0            knife
1          box set
2    jewellery set
3              NaN
Name: product_name, dtype: object
```

The `pattern = [{'POS': 'NOUN'},{'POS': 'NOUN','OP':'?'}]` pattern matches (combinations of) tokens that are both `NOUN`s. The second one is optional due to the `OP` operator set to `?`.

The `return max(results, key = lambda x: len(x.split()), default=np.nan)` part returns the item with the longest length (length measured in whitespace separated token count here).